# How to remove result files in runtime?

Tags: jmeter

I try to remove result files from a listener but it won't work. It seems JMeter lock the result files in runtime.
The screenshot below shows that I save the result to a csv file 'raw-result-table.csv'.
[image]

In Setup Thread, I add an OS Sampler to remove the result files. See screenshot below.
[image]

It cannot remove the files. I think it is because JMeter lock the file in runtime.
Please note that the OS Sampler is correct. It can remove the files when I disable the thread 'AD'. I've tried BeanShell script and result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you won't be able to delete the file which is being used for storing results of the current session. Also there are some issues with your test design:

1. You should not be using any Listeners, especially View Results in Table / Tree, [they consume a lot of resources and may ruin your test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing).
2. You should be [running your test in command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui). You can combine it with deleting the previous results file like:

   ```
   del *result*.csv && jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.csv
   ```

   Upon test completion you can open `result.csv` file in JMeter GUI and perform the analysis.
3. You should be using [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](http://groovy-lang.org/) instead of Beanshell (same applies to the functions, you should substitute __Beanshell() function with [__groovy() function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)) as Groovy has much better performance

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Regarding to #2, Is it possible to select fields that I want to see?

Comment: Yes, take a look at *jmeter.properties* file (lives under "bin" folder of your JMeter installation) and search for properties which names start with `jmeter.save.saveservice`. You can choose which metrics to store by modifying these properties. See [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) and [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) articles to learn more about JMeter properties and ways of setting and overriding them